# Tensorflow error while running segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation, jetson-xavier

I am using a Jetson Xavier NX to run segmentation as created by [Segmentation][1].
These are the versions of the libraries I am using
tensorflow - 1.15.4
keras - 2.1.5
python - 3.6.9

However when i run my program, I am getting the following error

```
2021-06-14 20:30:53.671609: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at random_op.cc:76 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3,3,128,128] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

This is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8


import mrcnn
#print(mrcnn)
import os
import sys
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import skimage.io
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Root directory of the project
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("../")
print(ROOT_DIR)


# Import Mask RCNN
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)  # To find local version of the library
from mrcnn import utils
import mrcnn.model as modellib
from mrcnn import visualize
# Import COCO config
sys.path.append(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "/Mask_RCNN/samples/coco/"))  # To find local version
import coco

#get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

# Directory to save logs and trained model
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "logs")

# Local path to trained weights file
COCO_MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
# Download COCO trained weights from Releases if needed
if not os.path.exists(COCO_MODEL_PATH):
    utils.download_trained_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH)

# Directory of images to run detection on
IMAGE_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "images")

class InferenceConfig(coco.CocoConfig):
    # Set batch size to 1 since we'll be running inference on
    # one image at a time. Batch size = GPU_COUNT * IMAGES_PER_GPU
    GPU_COUNT = 1
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1

config = InferenceConfig()
config.display()

# Create model object in inference mode.
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=config)

# Load weights trained on MS-COCO
model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True)

# COCO Class names
# Index of the class in the list is its ID. For example, to get ID of
# the teddy bear class, use: class_names.index('teddy bear')
class_names = ['BG', 'person', 'bicycle', 'car', 'motorcycle', 'airplane',
               'bus', 'train', 'truck', 'boat', 'traffic light',
               'fire hydrant', 'stop sign', 'parking meter', 'bench', 'bird',
               'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'sheep', 'cow', 'elephant', 'bear',
               'zebra', 'giraffe', 'backpack', 'umbrella', 'handbag', 'tie',
               'suitcase', 'frisbee', 'skis', 'snowboard', 'sports ball',
               'kite', 'baseball bat', 'baseball glove', 'skateboard',
               'surfboard', 'tennis racket', 'bottle', 'wine glass', 'cup',
               'fork', 'knife', 'spoon', 'bowl', 'banana', 'apple',
               'sandwich', 'orange', 'broccoli', 'carrot', 'hot dog', 'pizza',
               'donut', 'cake', 'chair', 'couch', 'potted plant', 'bed',
               'dining table', 'toilet', 'tv', 'laptop', 'mouse', 'remote',
               'keyboard', 'cell phone', 'microwave', 'oven', 'toaster',
               'sink', 'refrigerator', 'book', 'clock', 'vase', 'scissors',
               'teddy bear', 'hair drier', 'toothbrush']

import cv2
# Load a random image from the images folder
file_names = next(os.walk(IMAGE_DIR))[2]
image = skimage.io.imread("/sample_images/sample3.jpg")

# Run detection
results = model.detect([image], verbose=1)

# Visualize results
r = results[0]
visualize.display_instances(image, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'], 
                            class_names, r['scores'])
cv2.imwrite("hi.jpg",image)
```

I have run the same program on aws ec2. THe only difference was the tensorflow version (I used 1.8.0 gpu) there and it was working fine. Is the error caused by the tensorflow version?

**EDIT**
I have added this into the beginning of my code as shown in some github issue

```
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

I am still getting a warning and not getting out put

```
 Stats: 
Limit:                  2107527168
InUse:                   436697856
MaxInUse:                683784192
NumAllocs:                    1722
MaxAllocSize:            170917888

2021-06-15 12:58:33.338214: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:427] ***********************xx**_**************__________________________________________________________
2021-06-15 12:58:33.680104: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:305] Garbage collection: deallocate free memory regions (i.e., allocations) so that we can re-allocate a larger region to avoid OOM due to memory fragmentation. If you see this message frequently, you are running near the threshold of the available device memory and re-allocation may incur great performance overhead. You may try smaller batch sizes to observe the performance impact. Set TF_ENABLE_GPU_GARBAGE_COLLECTION=false if you'd like to disable this feature.
```

How I check if my gpu is alloted properly or not?
[1]: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN

Comment: That is a warning, not an error.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy The program isnt terminating though. What could be the reason?

Comment: Hi @AkshayAcharya! Have you checked in latest version 2.6 yet ? Please use test configurations from below to provide GPU support. You can use Profiler to optimize GPU performance.    Attaching Reference links.    https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu_performance_analysis        https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu